# C code acting unusual, where are the special characters coming from?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm experiencing unusual behavior of the output when changing the range of the array y[].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char x[50];
  int y[50];
  fgets(x, 50, stdin);
  for (int i; i<50; i++){
    printf("%c", x[i]);
  }
  printf("DONE\n");
  return 0;
}
```

To test the program i've been inputting '10 10 10' and I expect the input to be printed back out by the program followed by the 'DONE' statement.

However the code has been outputting the '10 10 10' with either '`?DONE' , '`;DONE' or someother variation of special characters.

If I comment out the 'int y[50]' it completely skips the for loop.

Coming from a python/swift/java background I have no idea whats going on and why the 'y' array is causing errors when im not even using it. Maybe it's just cuz im new to c but i hardly even know how to describe the issue (hence the crappy title)

NOTE* There is a point of the 'y' array but i've removed it from the program for simplicitys sake while trying to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @user3386109 erm...... that just breaks everything, fgets() doesn't return int so that'll just return the numbers ASCII values which is.... not the intended outcome. Nor does it fix the problems

Comment: Did you ever initialize `i`?  It looks uninitialized to me.

Comment: @Tim The intent was to show what the code was printing without the confusion of non-printable characters being output to the screen. A `char` in C is simply a small integer, which can be printed with `%d`. But @abelenky has found a problem with the code that I overlooked (rendering my suggestion moot).

Comment: Regarding: `for (int i; i<50; i++){`  this is missing the initialization `i` so the start value could be anything.  Suggest using: `for (int i = 0; i<50; i++){`

Comment: Regarding: `for (int i; i<50; i++){  printf("%c", x[i]);`  how do you know that 50 characters were read from `stdin`?  Much better to use: `for (size_t  i =0; x[i]; i++){  printf("%c", x[i]);`   which will stop when it encounters the NUL byte at the end of the string read by `fgets()

Comment: OT:  the posted code contains a 'magic' number '50'  'magic numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name.  Then use that meaningful name throughout the code

Answer (score 6):

`i` is uninitialized. Reading from an uninitialized variable causes undefined behavior. Often they'll be filled with whatever arbitrary data happened to be on the stack. Set `i` to `0`.

You should also stop looping when you hit the end of the string. Either stop when you hit `'\0'` or loop up to `strlen(x)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50 && x[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

or

```
int len = strlen(x);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to ONLY print what is captured x[], then change this:

```
for (int i; i<50; i++){
```

to this:

```
for (int i=0; (x[i]!='\0') && (i<50); i++){
```

Comment: John, you brought up a valid point.  fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and then adds terminating null byte ('\0').  So either (i<50) should just be removed since it's useless in the current implementation, or "if(i==49) break" line should be added to end of for loop.

Answer (score -2):

You are giving buffer a size of 50, using a portion on the size for your string, then printing all of the array. You want to only print the portion of the array that is your string. you can do this by doing the following.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char x[50];
  int y[50];
  fgets(x, 50, stdin);
  for (int i; i<strlen(x); i++){
    printf("%c", x[i]);
  }
  printf("DONE\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using an unutilized `i` is UB.  Repeated calls to `strlen(x)` are inefficient with compilers that do not recognize `x` did not change.  Suggest `for (int i=0; x[i]; i++) {`